# make filled shapes move in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following statement for drawing filled rectangler and cirle shapes in matlab.
What I have to add for those statement only to make shapes between start point and target point for each without collision.

```
fill([9.5 9.5 11.5 11.5 ],[12.6 14.6 14.6 12.6],'r');  %rectangler shape
hold on
r=1; 
color=[1 0 0]; 
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
fill(15+r*cos(t),8+r*sin(t),color); %circle shape
grid on
```

Comment: Could you define and give examples of your start and target point, please?

Comment: the centre point of each shape is the starting point for example for circle shape the starting point is S=[15 8]; we can asume the target point is T=[1  1];

Comment: So you have rectangled and circled objects. You want to move them around and make sure that they never overlap? Is that correct? And what should happen if they do overlap?

Comment: Yes Please, this is very correct

Comment: if they hit each other the direction of movement should be changed

Comment: You can't expect people to do all that for you. Try yourself and come back with specific questions when you get stuck

Comment: Thanks Luis, Now I just want to add a statement to make the two objects move please

Comment: Sorry but I thought your question was on how to check if they overlap?

Comment: No, Currently I have run the above code and get the two shapes, I just want them to move

Comment: That's a more reasonable request :-) I'm removing my downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example with a rectangle. The trick is to gradually modify the object properties, in this case its `'Vertices'`

```
origin_x = [9.5 9.5 11.5 11.5 ]; %// initial coordinates of vertices
origin_y = [12.6 14.6 14.6 12.6];
destination_x = origin_x + 3; %// final coordinates of vertices
destination_y = origin_y + 2;
n_steps = 100; %// number of "frames"
t_pause = .03; %// seconds between frames

h = fill(origin_x, origin_y, 'r'); %// create object at initial position
axis([8 16 10 18]) %// adjust as needed, to cover the desired area
axis equal %// same scale in both axes
axis manual %// prevent axes from auto-scaling
for t = linspace(0,1,n_steps)
    x = (1-t)*origin_x + t*destination_x; %// update x
    y = (1-t)*origin_y + t*destination_y; %// update y
    set(h, 'Vertices', [x(:) y(:)]) %// change object's position
    pause(t_pause) %// a pause is needed to make movement slower
    drawnow %// probably not needed after pause. Just in case
end
```

[image]

---

Example with a rectangle and a circle. The approach is similar: create both objects and update their `'Vertices'` property within the `for` loop.

```
%// Define rectangle values
origin_x1 = [9.5 9.5 11.5 11.5 ];
origin_y1 = [12.6 14.6 14.6 12.6];
destination_x1 = origin_x1 + 3;
destination_y1 = origin_y1 + 2;

%// Define circle values
r = 1;
v = linspace(0,2*pi);
origin_x2 = 15+r*cos(v);
origin_y2 = 10+r*sin(v);
destination_x2 = origin_x2 - 1;
destination_y2 = origin_y2 + 3;

%// Define movement speed
n_steps = 100;
t_pause = .03;

%// Create objects
h1 = fill(origin_x1, origin_y1, 'r');
hold on
h2 = fill(origin_x2, origin_y2, 'b');

axis([8 16 10 18])
axis equal
axis manual

%// Update properties
for t = linspace(0,1,n_steps)
    x1 = (1-t)*origin_x1 + t*destination_x1;
    y1 = (1-t)*origin_y1 + t*destination_y1;
    set(h1, 'Vertices', [x1(:) y1(:)])

    x2 = (1-t)*origin_x2 + t*destination_x2;
    y2 = (1-t)*origin_y2 + t*destination_y2;
    set(h2, 'Vertices', [x2(:) y2(:)])

    pause(t_pause)
    drawnow
end
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm... Sometimes I wonder why I seem so slow... :-). I was just about to post. You got my +1

Comment: @user3481947 It should be pretty obvious from my example. The approach is the same

Comment: I have run two objects. however they don't work simultaneously. When they first one finishes the second one starts.

Comment: Put both updates within the `for` loop: add similar lines `x2 = ...`, `y2 = ...`,  `set(h2, ...)` for the second object

Comment: @user3481947 I've included and example with the two objects

Comment: Dear Luis, Now it's very clear how to make many objects move simultaneously. I already have static envrionment, when I inserted this code into my main s-function the outcome get worse and MATLAB doesn't show me an erroe so I try to fix it. shall I send you my work to see what's going on to help me please

Comment: @user3481947 You can post it as a new question here in StackOverflow

Comment: Regarding to this question, it's possible to make the speed of each object is different.

Comment: @user3481947 Sure. Just specify the destination point further from the origin for one of the objects than for the other. For example, `destination_x2 = origin_x2 - 5; destination_y2 = origin_y2 + 10;
`

Comment: it's well done, but what the reason behind it, I need to know the speed value in m/s for each object.

Comment: @user3481947 Come on, it's an easy computation :-)

Comment: d=[Original(x,y)-Destination(x,y)]

Comment: then divide the distance over the time

Comment: Luis I suggest to send you my codes to see the difference

Comment: @user3481947 Sorry, I don't accept these questions by email or any means other than StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks Luis, Currently, in the above code, objects move form its original point to the destination. I need to add more than one destination for each object, maybe aftre reaching a destination 1, an object have to come back to its orginal.