# Simulation Error (Invalid hand object)

Tags: matlab

[image]

In the attached image I have two static objects, starting point and target point, the robot goes from start point to the target.

However when I add this code for another moving object, the simulation results show a continous  flash without robot movement:
the code for added moving objects is;

```
hold on
origin_x = [9.5 9.5 11.5 11.5 ]; %// initial coordinates of vertices
origin_y = [12.6 14.6 14.6 12.6];
destination_x = origin_x + 3; %// final coordinates of vertices
destination_y = origin_y + 2;
n_steps = 100; %// number of "frames"
t_pause = .03; %// seconds between frames

h = fill(origin_x, origin_y, 'b'); %// create object at initial position
for t = linspace(0,1,n_steps)
    x = (1-t)*origin_x + t*destination_x; %// update x
    y = (1-t)*origin_y + t*destination_y; %// update y
    set(h, 'Vertices', [x(:) y(:)]) %// change object's position
    pause(t_pause) %// a pause is needed to make movement slower
    drawnow %// probably not needed after pause. Just in case
end
```

Comment: This is related to [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24181618/2586922)

Comment: @user3481947: In your previous question Luis Mendo suggested a solution including `axis([8 16 10 18]);
axis equal;axis manual`, if I add these lines to your code everything is fine. The robot is not flashing, but Matlab automatically rescales the axis in your code.

Comment: the axis in my main code is so I didn't mention it here

Comment: the robot stopes movement and the screen flashing, and I read this message invalid hand object.

Comment: the above image is before adding new code obe for moving object

Comment: Yes Luis this is related to the previous question

Comment: Dear Luis, shall I send you my simulink codes to see the difference between to cases please

Comment: Dera Daniel, the problem is not in the above code, the problem appears when I insert this code with my main code