# Simultaneous animation at two axes in a matlab figure

Tags: matlab, animation, axes, simultaneous

First of all, i have to say that i run a Gui that has to axes, axes1, axes2 .Then i open a file an animate it in the axes1.Then i  open another file and animate in axes2. The problem is that i have a button,that when it pushed it must provoke the animation of both files in both axes simultaneously. Is it possible ?

My code for the button is

```
function compare_animation_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
play_Callback(hObject,eventdata, handles);%axes1
play_results_Callback(hObject,eventdata, handles) %axe2
```

The problem is in the animation code, because the only file that is animated is the second.The code for the animation is:

```
handles = startAnimation(~,handles)
global VARS_GLOBAL_ANIM
% pause the animation that might currently be running
pauseAnimation;

% prepare animation controls
frames_total = max([handles.mot.nframes]);
set(handles.slider_animate, 'Enable','on','Max', frames_total+.001,'Value', 1,'SliderStep', [1/frames_total 1/frames_total]);
set(handles.slider_speed, 'Enable','on');
speed = get(handles.slider_speed,'Value');


% set some properties for the animation
%not important 


%rehash path 
set(gcf,'CurrentAxes',handles.axes_animate);

cla reset;
% start animation
VARS_GLOBAL_ANIM.animation_paused = false;
new_animate(handles.skel,handles.mot,1,speed,{},{},{'updateAnimationSlider',handles.slider_animate},true);
```

Last the last function that is called is new_animate (...), at the end of the function Start_animation. In the function the only code that refers to figure or axes is :

```
new_animate_initGraphics;

desired_frame_time = VARS_GLOBAL_ANIM.mot(1).frameTime;

if (~isempty(VARS_GLOBAL_ANIM.figure_camera_file))
    h = str2func(VARS_GLOBAL_ANIM.figure_camera_file);
    feval(h, gca);
end

if (~isempty(VARS_GLOBAL_ANIM.figure_position))
    set(gcf,'position',VARS_GLOBAL_ANIM.figure_position);
end
```

The function new_animate_initGraphics(if is needed i can upload it)is to big to have it all..Of course the code isn't mine. I can't understand how to use the gca properly in order not to lose one animation and both simultaneously??

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Would [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24182656/2545927) help?

Comment: I believe no.That is at the same axe.I want 2 axes to animate 2 different sequences.I may try to put both animation at the same but i think the problem is that i can;t figure how to avoid the gca,'Current axes' method